# Use Find-command to filter out files with specific pattern to terminal

Tags: linux, grep, find

I want to show all files with the name "index.php" in a specific area of my machine. For this I wrote this code-line:

```
-find /iu/cuve/u3 -name "index.php"
```

I want it to only show the lines witch include "index.php" in it, but this command shows a bunch of other lines witch does not include "index.php". Many of them ends with "Permission denied", maybe thats why I can't see the "index.php" part of the line.

I tried to add a -exec grep command to it, but didn't get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver. It pointed me in the right direction. Fixed it with this line:


"find /iu/cube/u3 index.php 2>&- | grep index.php"

Answer (score 0):

Got my wanted result with:

```
find /iu/cube/u3 index.php 2>&- | grep index.php
```